# Why isn't \newline or \\ working?

Tags: line-breaking, resume

I am using a template to make my resume, I usually just use `\newline` or `\\` to skip a line. However it isn't working here. My line is too long and it is overflowing the document, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}} 
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
\name{asdasd} % Your name

\address{\href{mailto:asdasd@gmail.com}{asdasd@gmail.com} \\ \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in//}{linkedin.com/} \\ \href{https://github.com/}{github.com/} \\ \newline %newline here does not work
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa ADDRESS HERE aaaaaaaa} %here is the line overflowing
```

Comment: Please provide this as a full minimal example that other have a chance to compile and test. The example is incomplete

Comment: Additionally, it might be a good idea to mention where `resume.cls` is located as that is not a know class.

Comment: Use `\\ ~\newline`